# Deploying to AWS Lambda from Visual Studio Team Services, Dotnet Lamba Not Found

Tags: aws-lambda, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have created a .Net Core 2.0 Web API and am trying to deploy it using Visual Studio Team Services and the AWS Lambda .Net Tools, according to this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/working-with-lambda-functions-and-visual-studio-team-services/.

But when the task runs in VSTS it throws this error:

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-lambda"

Here is the full log of the task:

```
2018-01-27T02:55:21.9538582Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy to Lambda:  
2018-01-27T02:55:21.9749412Z ==============================================================================
2018-01-27T02:55:21.9749717Z Task         : AWS Lambda .NET Core Deployment
2018-01-27T02:55:21.9749955Z Description  : Build and deploy a Serverless .NET Core application or AWS Lambda function
2018-01-27T02:55:21.9750152Z Version      : 1.0.17
2018-01-27T02:55:21.9750334Z Author       : Amazon Web Services
2018-01-27T02:55:21.9750571Z Help         : Please refer to [AWS Lambda Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/) for more information on working with AWS Lambda.
2018-01-27T02:55:21.9750859Z ==============================================================================
2018-01-27T02:55:23.4482254Z d4194695-5ae1-4063-ab6c-c39aa4079814 exists true
2018-01-27T02:55:23.4524112Z Deploying Lambda project at d:\a\1\s
2018-01-27T02:55:23.4545880Z Beginning dotnet restore
2018-01-27T02:55:23.4729777Z Path to tool: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
2018-01-27T02:55:23.4760281Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" restore
2018-01-27T02:55:25.2373341Z   Restoring packages for d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.API\SimOpSolutions.API.csproj...
2018-01-27T02:55:25.2374456Z   Restoring packages for d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Domain\SimOpSolutions.Domain.csproj...
2018-01-27T02:55:35.5704175Z   Installing System.Threading.Overlapped 4.3.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.5879102Z   Installing System.Net.WebHeaderCollection 4.3.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.6356230Z   Installing System.Net.NetworkInformation 4.3.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.6438188Z   Installing System.Data.Common 4.3.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.6990259Z   Installing ServiceStack.Text.Core 5.0.2.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.6999574Z   Installing ServiceStack.Interfaces.Core 5.0.2.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.7024446Z   Installing System.Xml.XmlSerializer 4.3.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.7541486Z   Installing System.Net.Requests 4.3.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.8301653Z   Installing System.Reflection.DispatchProxy 4.4.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.8311199Z   Installing System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler 4.4.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.8311429Z   Installing System.Net.WebHeaderCollection 4.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.8313073Z   Installing MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 4.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.8469303Z   Installing MediatR 4.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.9290745Z   Installing ServiceStack.Common.Core 5.0.2.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.9305266Z   Installing ServiceStack.Client.Core 5.0.2.
2018-01-27T02:55:35.9315268Z   Installing System.Linq.Queryable 4.3.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:36.3981940Z   Installing System.Private.ServiceModel 4.4.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:36.5638519Z   Installing System.Net.Requests 4.0.11.
2018-01-27T02:55:37.1019223Z   Installing Bogus 22.0.2.
2018-01-27T02:55:37.2144033Z   Installing FluentValidation.AspNetCore 7.4.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:38.3640693Z   Installing AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 3.3.5.
2018-01-27T02:55:38.4332497Z   Installing ServiceStack.Aws.Core 5.0.2.
2018-01-27T02:55:40.1039314Z   Installing FluentValidation 7.4.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:40.4885137Z   Installing AWSSDK.Core 3.3.19.
2018-01-27T02:55:40.7273199Z   Installing AWSSDK.S3 3.3.16.2.
2018-01-27T02:55:44.9860545Z   Installing AWSSDK.SQS 3.3.3.2.
2018-01-27T02:55:45.3974215Z   Installing System.ServiceModel.Primitives 4.4.0.
2018-01-27T02:55:48.0217564Z   Installing AWSSDK.Core 3.3.21.6.
2018-01-27T02:55:48.3023994Z   Installing ServiceStack.Core 5.0.2.
2018-01-27T02:56:24.2979807Z   Installing System.Globalization 4.3.0-preview1-24530-04.
2018-01-27T02:56:24.3991676Z   Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.1.0-preview1-24530-04.
2018-01-27T02:56:24.5524420Z   Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.1.0-preview1-24530-04.
2018-01-27T02:56:24.7613877Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 1.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:24.9467558Z   Installing System.Net.WebSockets 4.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:25.2402869Z   Installing AWSSDK.CloudFormation 3.3.9.
2018-01-27T02:56:25.3091012Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions 1.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:25.4939689Z   Installing AWSSDK.IdentityManagement 3.3.5.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:25.5379484Z   Installing Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:25.6977057Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool 1.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:25.9898745Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities 1.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:26.0239197Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions 1.0.4.
2018-01-27T02:56:26.0953771Z   Installing AWSSDK.Lambda 3.3.12.
2018-01-27T02:56:26.2492646Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions 1.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:26.2862688Z   Installing AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup 3.3.4.
2018-01-27T02:56:26.4454096Z   Installing System.Security.Claims 4.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:26.5571073Z   Installing Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer 2.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:26.7962213Z   Installing System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.3.0-preview1-24530-04.
2018-01-27T02:56:26.9275190Z   Installing System.Runtime 4.3.0-preview1-24530-04.
2018-01-27T02:56:27.0346748Z   Installing AWSSDK.Route53 3.3.13.
2018-01-27T02:56:27.0776396Z   Installing EnyimMemcachedCore 2.1.0.2.
2018-01-27T02:56:27.0795680Z   Installing System.Collections 4.3.0-preview1-24530-04.
2018-01-27T02:56:28.1480472Z   Installing System.ComponentModel.Primitives 4.1.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:28.2575492Z   Installing FluentScheduler 5.3.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:28.5952544Z   Installing Amazon.Lambda.Core 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:29.0640692Z   Installing Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore 2.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:29.0642148Z   Installing Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json 1.1.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:29.4093064Z   Installing Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:30.2697878Z   Installing Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 1.1.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:30.2918015Z   Installing System.Runtime.Loader 4.3.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:30.4510158Z   Installing YamlDotNet.Signed 4.3.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:30.7186809Z   Installing Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI 1.1.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:31.9071285Z   Installing Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger 1.1.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:32.0019769Z   Installing Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen 1.1.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:32.4263403Z   Installing AWSSDK.Core 3.3.13.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:33.5812531Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 1.0.2.
2018-01-27T02:56:33.7809983Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.2.
2018-01-27T02:56:33.8890341Z   Installing Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents 1.1.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:34.0549459Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:34.3940158Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:34.7082747Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:34.8651409Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:34.9448306Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles 1.0.4.
2018-01-27T02:56:34.9454751Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded 1.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:35.1961654Z   Installing System.Xml.XPath 4.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:35.2657937Z   Installing AutoMapper 6.2.2.
2018-01-27T02:56:35.3431628Z   Installing AWSSDK.CloudFront 3.3.6.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:36.9277797Z   Installing AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity 3.3.2.17.
2018-01-27T02:56:36.9937610Z   Installing AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider 3.3.8.
2018-01-27T02:56:37.0874877Z   Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging 1.1.5.
2018-01-27T02:56:37.1878915Z   Installing AWSSDK.Route53Domains 3.3.1.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:37.4613163Z   Installing BouncyCastle.NetCore 1.8.1.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:37.5422426Z   Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect 2.1.5.
2018-01-27T02:56:37.6076035Z   Installing JWT 3.1.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:37.6904483Z   Installing System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.1.5.
2018-01-27T02:56:37.7316937Z   Installing RestSharp.NetCore 105.2.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:38.0596877Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.0.4.
2018-01-27T02:56:38.1068926Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json 1.0.4.
2018-01-27T02:56:38.1077196Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer 1.0.4.
2018-01-27T02:56:38.1225080Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations 1.0.4.
2018-01-27T02:56:39.0309484Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 1.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:39.1692383Z   Installing System.ComponentModel 4.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:39.5362783Z   Installing System.Linq.Expressions 4.1.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:40.4614046Z   Installing System.Diagnostics.StackTrace 4.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:40.5563460Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:40.5755326Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:40.7212997Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:40.7777494Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:40.7966177Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:40.8577722Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Options 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:40.9128086Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:41.5171542Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:41.5591083Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:41.6475736Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:41.8938566Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions 1.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.0979387Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 1.0.4.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.0980587Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 1.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.0981410Z   Installing System.Text.Encodings.Web 4.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.0982053Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 1.0.2.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.0982656Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders 1.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.0983470Z   Installing AWSSDK.SecurityToken 3.3.3.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.0983969Z   Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols 2.1.5.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.2247233Z   Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens 5.1.5.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.2611182Z   Installing System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.1.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.2791682Z   Installing System.Collections.Specialized 4.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.2846406Z   Installing System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters 4.3.0-preview1-24530-04.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.8789195Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization 1.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.8789800Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 1.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.9626175Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Options 1.0.2.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.9769780Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions 1.0.4.
2018-01-27T02:56:45.9906831Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 1.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:46.0981601Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:46.4138385Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:47.6568391Z   Installing System.ComponentModel.Annotations 4.1.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:47.8091994Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions 1.0.4.
2018-01-27T02:56:48.0526415Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Localization 1.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:48.1983931Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:48.2288283Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:48.5258234Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:48.8960676Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:49.0181709Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:49.2159622Z   Installing Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:50.5518262Z   Installing System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:50.5519211Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:50.5519880Z   Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 1.0.0.
2018-01-27T02:56:50.5520167Z   Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 1.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:56:50.5520585Z   Installing Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 1.0.3.
2018-01-27T02:57:01.1940712Z d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.API\SimOpSolutions.API.csproj : warning NU1603: RestSharp.NetCore 105.2.3 depends on System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters (>= 4.0.0-rc4-24217-03) but System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters 4.0.0-rc4-24217-03 was not found. An approximate best match of System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters 4.3.0-preview1-24530-04 was resolved. [d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.sln]
2018-01-27T02:58:17.0409023Z   Generating MSBuild file d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Domain\obj\SimOpSolutions.Domain.csproj.nuget.g.props.
2018-01-27T02:58:19.4261118Z   Generating MSBuild file d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Domain\obj\SimOpSolutions.Domain.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
2018-01-27T02:58:19.4275775Z   Restore completed in 2.83 min for d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Domain\SimOpSolutions.Domain.csproj.
2018-01-27T02:58:19.4276367Z   Restoring packages for d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Infrastructure\SimOpSolutions.Infrastructure.csproj...
2018-01-27T02:58:25.1466415Z   Generating MSBuild file d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.API\obj\SimOpSolutions.API.csproj.nuget.g.props.
2018-01-27T02:58:25.1469733Z   Generating MSBuild file d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.API\obj\SimOpSolutions.API.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
2018-01-27T02:58:25.1683187Z   Restore completed in 3 min for d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.API\SimOpSolutions.API.csproj.
2018-01-27T02:58:25.1705188Z   Restoring packages for d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Tasks\SimOpSolutions.Tasks.csproj...
2018-01-27T02:58:25.2725896Z d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Tasks\SimOpSolutions.Tasks.csproj : warning NU1603: RestSharp.NetCore 105.2.3 depends on System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters (>= 4.0.0-rc4-24217-03) but System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters 4.0.0-rc4-24217-03 was not found. An approximate best match of System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters 4.3.0-preview1-24530-04 was resolved. [d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.sln]
2018-01-27T02:58:25.3842785Z   Generating MSBuild file d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Tasks\obj\SimOpSolutions.Tasks.csproj.nuget.g.props.
2018-01-27T02:58:25.3849002Z   Generating MSBuild file d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Tasks\obj\SimOpSolutions.Tasks.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
2018-01-27T02:58:25.4011791Z   Restore completed in 215.01 ms for d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Tasks\SimOpSolutions.Tasks.csproj.
2018-01-27T02:58:25.4034095Z   Restoring packages for d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.API\SimOpSolutions.API.csproj...
2018-01-27T02:58:28.0818820Z   Generating MSBuild file d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Infrastructure\obj\SimOpSolutions.Infrastructure.csproj.nuget.g.props.
2018-01-27T02:58:28.0819787Z   Generating MSBuild file d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Infrastructure\obj\SimOpSolutions.Infrastructure.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
2018-01-27T02:58:28.0958022Z   Restore completed in 9.65 sec for d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.Infrastructure\SimOpSolutions.Infrastructure.csproj.
2018-01-27T02:58:28.5158388Z   Restoring packages for d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.API\SimOpSolutions.API.csproj...
2018-01-27T02:58:28.7015042Z   Installing YamlDotNet.Signed 4.2.1.
2018-01-27T02:58:28.7015669Z   Installing AWSSDK.Lambda 3.3.10.
2018-01-27T02:58:28.7016068Z   Installing Amazon.Lambda.Tools 2.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:59:49.1223089Z   Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Contracts 2.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:59:49.1248772Z   Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools 2.0.1.
2018-01-27T02:59:56.4196984Z   Restore completed in 1.47 min for d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.API\SimOpSolutions.API.csproj.
2018-01-27T02:59:56.8923026Z   Restore completed in 1.52 min for d:\a\1\s\SimOpSolutions.API\SimOpSolutions.API.csproj.
2018-01-27T02:59:56.9548214Z Beginning Serverless Deployment
2018-01-27T02:59:56.9549299Z Path to tool: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
2018-01-27T02:59:56.9552784Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" lambda deploy-serverless --disable-interactive true --region us-east-1
2018-01-27T02:59:57.1481754Z No executable found matching command "dotnet-lambda"
2018-01-27T02:59:57.2033504Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
2018-01-27T02:59:57.2414775Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy to Lambda:
```

Comment: What if you deploy manully by `dotnet lambda` command? And It seems you are using Hosted VS2017 agent, what if you use private agent (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I changed the path to the Project to include the full path to the .csproj file then the Deployment started to work.

Comment: No idea why this isn't set by default... just wasted hours

Comment: Since it's the approved answer, I wish I knew what it meant. Maybe an example would make it clearer.

Answer (score 11):

I had to add a DotNetCliToolReference to the lambda tools in my .csproj file of the lambda project:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Tools" Version="2.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error any time I try to do this: `Package Amazon.Lambda.Tools 3.2.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Amazon.Lambda.Tools 3.2.3 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1) / any`. It appears that the package is incompatible with my project for some reason, using the standard Lambda project template. `Package 'Amazon.Lambda.Tools' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project`

Answer (score 9):

I got similar issue, and below is how I solve it

[image: No executable found matching command "dotnet-lambda"]

install Amazon.Lambda.Tools to the gloable, you can build it anywhere

```
dotnet tool install --global Amazon.Lambda.Tools --version 3.1.1
```

update to latest version

```
dotnet tool update --global Amazon.Lambda.Tools
```

then you can build in by cmd line in the project folder

```
dotnet-lambda package
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Issue is due to "Amazon.Lambda.Tools" NuGet package not getting downloaded even after "dotnet restore" (Check solution Explorer-->Dependencies-->NuGet) . 
To resolve issue run "dotnet add package Amazon.Lambda.Tools --version 2.1.1" in packet manager console inside your project folder i.e "cd .\YourProject")

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amazon.Lambda.Tools/2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but the steps above didn't work for me. But they helped me get the issue sorted. I'm including the steps I had to take in case someone needs the same fix I did.

First I had to change the agent pool to be '**Hosted VS2017**'.

For the first task in my pipeline I installed the Amazon Lambda Tools using the Command Line Task. 
The script I used was just '*dotnet tool install --global Amazon.Lambda.Tools --version 3.2.3*'. Screenshot is below and I had no other changes in that task other then adding the script.

[image: Command Line steps]

I then added a task for AWS Lambda .NET Core. Screenshot below of options I filled out. The package-only output was just the name of the zip that was generated. The path to lambda project needs to be the .csproj file that contains your function.

[image: Lambda package only steps]

Screenshot below are the steps I added to get it working. Once I queue this build it installs the lambda tools package on the agent, then it generates the zip file. Hopefully this helps others.
[image: Build pipeline steps]